# How to open and manage new tabs with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open a new tab with the 'https://www.gmail.com' url, then pick some info and return to the first page, I'm using the CTRL + t command to open the new tab, but, how can I switch between the two pages?
My code piece:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "t")
```

Actual code:

```
            bot = self.bot

            guids = bot.window_handles()

            time.sleep(2)

            bot.execute_script("window.open()")

            bot.get('https://gmail.com')

            time.sleep(1)
```

Python version = Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#current window
    first_tab = bot.window_handles[0]
#create new tab
    bot.execute_script("window.open()")
#move to new tab
    new_tab = bot.window_handles[1]
    bot.switch_to.window(new_tab)
    bot.get('https://gmail.com')
#switch to first tab
    bot.switch_to.window(first_tab)
```

Comment: I'm having these errors: ```Instance of 'WebDriver' has no 'getWindowHandles' member```, and: ```Instance of 'WebDriver' has no 'getWindowHandle' member```

Comment: updated my answer - it's driver.window_handles() and driver.switch_to_window(guid)

Comment: Hey, actually, I'm having an error instead: ```TypeError: 'list' object is not callable```

Comment: you can use it like this  window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)